# List all saved tokens for the current identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project, which uses the Microsoft OpenIdConnect framework to enable OAuth2 + OpenId as the Authorization and Identity provider for my project.

I would like to view the incoming tokens, when a user signs on the the page, for debugging purposes.

I have setup my MVC project Startup.cs as follows:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "id_token";
    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

Currently I can get the id_token by writing:

```
var idToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

And the Access token by writing:

```
var accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

But I had to figure out the names by myself, and would like an easier way to look into what is being saved.

**Is there a way to list all the saved tokens?**